# Fix for gallery in tabs?

Tags: tabs

I need major help =/ Hoping someone can help me find a solution. So I am trying to use photomosaic plugin or just mosaic gallery.

http://goo.gl/rTF7kL

Thats the page I have set up on. The first set of tabs, is it possible to remove the image links? So no one can click it?

The second set of tabs is using the photomosaic plugin. But if you notice, the second, third, etc tab does not show the photomosaic gallery, and it just shows as empty.

Can someone help me figure out how to remove the image clicking on the gallery on the first set of tabs, or help me figure out how to show the gallery in more than 1 tab on the second set of tabs at the bottom of the page?

Thank you so much.

Comment: welcome to SO. Please post relevant code (HTML, CSS, JS etc) so that we see your issues and try and fix them. This should be separated into two questions/posts on SO.

Comment: Hi, well, it would be hard to since the first set of tabs is part of the theme, using visual composer plugin.

The second set of tabs is using a tab plugin with photomosaic plugin.

http://codecanyon.net/item/photomosaic-for-wordpress/243422
This is the plugin used for the 2nd set of tabs, located at the bottom of my website.